# C++ delete class variable from function

Tags: c++, memory

```
class Foo {
    // some codes
}

class Bar {
    // Constructor, Destructor
    vector<Foo*> fooVector;

    Foo* getFoo(long index)
    {
        return fooVector[index];
    }

    long addFoo(Foo* foo)
    {
        fooVector.push_back(foo);
        return fooVector.size() - 1;
    }

    void removeFoo(long index)
    {
        delete fooVector[index];
    }
}
```

This is my codes.
But I want to change `removeFoo` like

```
void removeFoo(long index)
{
    Foo* foo = getFoo(index);
    delete foo;
}
```

Is it right? I can't sure about this.

In my thought, It may delete `foo` variable.

Please tell me whether it is right or not.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `vector<Foo>`, is there any reason you need to store pointers and not actual objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the memory for the pointer was allocated by `new` then yes that's how you free it. However, that won't remove the pointer from the vector, so afterwards your vector have an entry that no longer point to valid memory. You need to [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) it from the vector.

Also note that in modern C++ there is seldom a need to use pointers anymore, except for polymorphism really. If you don't have pointers, you don't have to worry about freeing memory or stray pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Using such method you are bypassing most of the benefits you gained from using `vector`. When removing elements by `delete` (which is valid in the case you described) you will rubbish your `fooVector` with non-valid data pointers to some undeclared/invalid memory areas.

It would be handy if, in addition, you showed us how you actually create `fooVector` elements.

In my opinion, both ways that you presented are valid in C++, but they will lead to hard-to-rely-on results and rubbish in your vector.